# C++: What is the proper way of organising a programs subsystems?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton, global-variables, modularity

Imagine you have a large application project, the code is split into a range of subsystems implemented as classes derived from CBaseSubsystem.

Here already comes my first question:

- Is it a good idea to organize subsystems as classes [derived from a base class]?

Then, you have your subsystem classes. Now, you will need create have instances of them somewhere. But where?

- Is it a good idea to have every subsystem instance stored in a global variable, for example:
  `extern CEventSystem* g_EventSystem;`
- Where should the instances be actually created? All together in a main()-like function?
- Or is it better to avoid global variables entirely and organize the instances in a `CSubsystemManager` class or the like?
- Would using singleton classes be an appropriate approach?

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161776/c-should-i-use-global-variables-or-class-member-pointers-to-communicate-betwee). I'd avoid [Singleton](http://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/singleton-considered-stupid), because it is absolutely unnecessary here and brings about [many other issues](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI).

Create the instances in a main-like routine. If something needs a system, provide access to it through some means, be it a parameter passed directly to that something or a container that provides access to these systems (IE: CSubSystemManager). You likely don't need to go so far as to write CSubSystemManager.

Avoid global state, there's a reason it has a stigma.

Comment: +1 for highlighting the perils of global state and discouraging the Singleton anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a way to access an instance of each subsystem, I would avoid using "extern" and instead go with a singleton that gives you access to an instance of CSubsystemManager.  The manager itself can take care of instantiating and managing your subsystem objects.

Comment: But every time one subsystem wants to communicate with another, it will need to "find" the other one via the subsystem manager - won't what be a problem?

Comment: It depends on how expensive the lookup function is.  You could store the subsystem instances in a vector that's indexed by a int (you could define an enum value for each subsystem type). alternatively, you could you could do the lookup for the relevant subsystems on object construction and store a reference in a class variable.  That way, you'd only do the lookup once.

Comment: The latter one sounds like a reasonable solution, yes, thank you

Comment: What you're refering to is classic "find-and-bind". you need a Registry (impl wise a simple hashtable will do) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to talk theory rather than provide a concrete question then consider designing in terms of a combination of [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) with the possibility of [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) in subsystems which may implement a similar operation for a range of different object types.

The main subsystem Factory is itself a singleton whose purpose is I hope obvious. Use lazy evaluation to allow only required subsystem objects to be loaded as needed. You may want to consider providing each subsystem with a reference counting mechanism which will allow them to be dropped when no longer needed. Some subsystems may themselves be singletons and/or may also implement Strategy pattern to provide a particular service for a range of class types.
This service may be for example validation, rendering, serialisation etc.

The value judgement of whether it is a "good idea" to build your application in this way is not for me to say. I would rather let older wisdom speak to that.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would create a combo of a singleton Registry, AbstractFactory and Factory.

```
//in base module

class ISubsystem{} //an interface for a subsystem

//in module code
Registry::instance()->registerFactory("subsystem1",new Subsystem1Factory());

//in user code
IFactory* factory = Registry::instance()->getFactory("subsystem1");
ISubsystem* subsystem = factory->createObject(...); //you can implement whatever policy in factory impl. (like singleton etc.)
```